# Why variable does change to zero when it is compared?

Tags: c, random, comparison

I have the code below. The problem is with variable `r`, which first holds a random number between 1-10. Later it is compared inside a loop to a user input number. The loop ends when the user guesses the randomly generated number.

I am using `short` type for the guess, and `int` for the randomly generated number `r`. The point is that after the first guess of the user, `r` becomes 0 and I don't know why. This problem does not happen if `guess` is an `int`.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <time.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main(int argc, const char * argv[]) {
    srand(time(NULL));
    int r = (rand()%10)+1;
    short guess = -1;
    printf("%d\n", r);
    while ((guess)!= r){
        printf("%d\n", (int) guess);
        printf("%d\n", guess);
        printf("%d\n", r);
        printf("Give me a number from 1 to 10: ");
        scanf("%d",&guess);
        if (guess> r){
            printf("The number is lower\n");
        }
        else if (guess<r){
            printf("The number is higher\n");
        }
        else {
            printf("Corrent!\n");
        }
    }
    return 0;
}
```

An output example would be:

```
7
-1
-1
7
Give me a number from 1 to 10: 5
The number is lower
5
5
0
Give me a number from 1 to 10:
```

Comment: 'short guess'.......'scanf("%d",&guess);'

Comment: Re: "This problem does not happen if guess is an int". Reminds me of a story. Man goes to see a doctor, says "Hey, doc, it hurts when I do this". Doctor replies "Well, stop *doing* that". :-)

Comment: Tip: A good compiler with all its warnings enabled will  warning about `short guess = -1;
        scanf("%d",&guess);`.  Save yourself (and us) time by enabling all warnings  - or use a better compiler.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem is here:

```
scanf("%d",&guess);
```

The variable `guess` is a `short`, but the `%d` format specifier to `scanf` expect a pointer to an `int`.  Using the wrong format specifer to `printf` or `scanf` invokes [undefined behavior](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Undefined_behavior).

What most likely happened is that an `int` on your system is larger than a `short`, resulting in writing to bytes in memory past where `guess` resides, overwriting nearby variables, in this case `r`.  This behavior however is not guaranteed and could change with seemingly unrelated code changes.

Either use the correct format specifier:

```
scanf("%hd",&guess);
```

Or change the type of `guess` to `int`.  Since there's no real reason to use a `short` here, I'd recommend the latter.

Comment: Indeed. Thank you very much! I am sorry for the dumb question, I am just starting to learn c.